# How to delete a particular column in csv file without pandas library

Tags: python, csvreader, csvwriter

I am trying to delete particular columns in csv file.

CSV file:

```
Name,Age,YearofService,Department,Allocation
Birla,49,12,Welding,Production
Robin,38,10,Molding,Production
```

I am trying to delete Entire column having column header "Department" and "Allocation".

My code :

```
 with open(input.csv,'r') as i:
    with open(output.csv,'w',new line='') as o:
       reader=csv.reader(i)
       writer = csv.writer(o)
       for row in reader:
          for i in range(len(row)):
            if row[i]!="Department" and row[i]!="Allocation":
              writer.writerow(row)
```

My output:

```
Name
Birla
Robin
Age
49
38
YearofService
12
10
```

Expected output:

```
Name,Age,YearofService
Birla,49,12
Robin,38,10
```

We cannot gaurantee Department and Allocation will be in column header position "3" and "4".
thats y am using iteration through length of row

Comment: Read first row (the one with the headers). Find index numbers for the columns you want to delete. Delete them in the first row (larger index first) and write row to output CSV. Then read the remaining rows one by one and for each delete the unwanted columns and write the row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the `csv.DictReader` and `csv.DictWriter` classes are very handy:

```py
import csv

with open("input.csv") as instream, open("output.csv", "w") as outstream:
    # Setup the input
    reader = csv.DictReader(instream)

    # Setup the output fields
    output_fields = reader.fieldnames
    output_fields.remove("Department")
    output_fields.remove("Allocation")

    # Setup the output
    writer = csv.DictWriter(
        outstream,
        fieldnames=output_fields,
        extrasaction="ignore",  # Ignore extra dictionary keys/values
    )

    # Write to the output
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(reader)
```

Notes

- For input, each of the row will be a dictionary such as

  ```
  {'Name': 'Birla', 'Age': '49', 'YearofService': '12', 'Department': 'Welding', 'Allocation': 'Production'}
  ```
- For output, we remove those columns (fields) that we don't need, see `output_fields`
- The `extraaction` parameter tells `DictReader` to ignore extra keys/values from the dictionaries

## Update

In order to remove columns from a CSV file we need to

1. Open the input file, reader all the rows, close it
2. Open it again to write.

Here is the code, which I modified from the above

```py
import csv

with open("input.csv") as instream:
    # Setup the input
    reader = csv.DictReader(instream)
    rows = list(reader)

    # Setup the output fields
    output_fields = reader.fieldnames
    output_fields.remove("Department")
    output_fields.remove("Allocation")

with open("input.csv", "w") as outstream:
    # Setup the output
    writer = csv.DictWriter(
        outstream,
        fieldnames=output_fields,
        extrasaction="ignore",  # Ignore extra dictionary keys/values
    )

    # Write to the output
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: If i dont need a seperate file(output).Am i allowed to remove those columns  in same input file.Do we need writer on that condition.

Comment: Please see my update above.

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about DictReader

Comment: It was printing an one empty spacce in between rows

Comment: @BalajiRB Would you please post a portion of your input data file? Are there empty lines in there?

Comment: Your code worked as expected but it gives empty rows inbetween values.I am checking on those.My csv file doesnt have empty values.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The quickest and most easy way is to just open in it in excel and delete the column that you want, i know it isn't what you ask for but it is the first thing it comes to my mind for a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like this (but still it's better to use pandas):

```
import csv

def delete_cols(file: str, cols_to_delete: list):
    cols_to_delete = set(cols_to_delete)
    with open(file) as file, open('output.csv', 'w') as output:
        reader = list(csv.reader(file))
        headers = reader[0]

        indexes_to_delete = [idx for idx, elem in enumerate(headers) if elem in cols_to_delete]
        result = [[o for idx, o in enumerate(obj) if idx not in indexes_to_delete] for obj in reader]

        writer = csv.writer(output)
        writer.writerows(result)


delete_cols('data.csv', ['Department', 'Allocation'])
```

file `output.csv`:

```
Name,Age,YearofService
Birla,49,12
Robin,38,10
```

Comment: Thanks Funnydman..I am not allowed to install any libraries

Comment: It also  create a empty rows..My csv file doesnt have any empty rows and columns